# How to get Category info in detail page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page where i show products under their subcategory url's and in top of my page i want to print the `subcategory title` and `subcategory image`, how can I do that?

here is my function:

```
public function productsubcategory($slug, $subslug)
    {
        $products = Product::whereHas('subcategory', function($q) use($subslug){
        $q->where('slug',$subslug);
      })->paginate(12);
        return view('frontend.subcategories', compact('products'));
    }
```

and I show my products with foreach like `@foreach($products as $product) ....`

Comment: What is the problem??

Comment: @MahfuzShishir I want show subcategory info.

Comment: What is $slug and $subslug?

Comment: slug of category and slug of subcategory url will be like `url/category/xx/subcategory/xxx`

Answer (score 0):

The best way you doing is One to Many relationship. Use ORM for that. You will get details here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent

In your Category.php Model

```
public function subcategories()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory', 'category_id');
}
```

In you Subcategory.php Model

```
public function category()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
}

public function products()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'subcategory_id');
}
```

And your Product.php Model

```
public function subcategory()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Subcategory', 'subcategory_id');
}
```

And you will get subcategory list
    $subcategories = Category::find($id)->subcategories;

And You get products

```
foreach($subcategories as $subCat)
{
  //your code
}
```

And here is another link for One to Many relationship. If you read details it will help you. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: currently i'm getting my products under subcategories that's out of issue, what i want to get is subcategory info in their page.  example, I'm in `HP` subcategory page and I have 20 products which i can see, I want also show `HP->image` and title` top of my those 20 products so people know which subcategory page they are in.

Comment: When you have subcategory_id you can easily find the info of subcategory. $subcat_info = Subcategory::find($subcategory_id); then pass the $subcat_info in your view.

Comment: but the thing is i get my subcategory pages by slug and not id as you see in my function

Comment: One question for you. Subcategory table and Products table contain any relation?

Comment: only id's in DB and model's relations

Comment: do you have any idea? `i can get my products list just need that subcategory info` :)

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED

I added another query in my function so totally become like this:

```
public function productsubcategory($slug, $subslug)
    {
        $products = Product::whereHas('subcategory', function($q) use($subslug){
        $q->where('slug',$subslug);
        })->paginate(12);
        $productss = Product::whereHas('subcategory', function($q) use($subslug){
        $q->where('slug',$subslug);
        })->first();
        return view('frontend.subcategories', compact('products', 'productss'));
    }
```

And here is how i show my `subcategory` info in their pages.

```
{{$productss->Subcategory->title}}
```

Hope this help others.